bottom navigation : icons are not fully visible
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="#CEF6F5"
        app:itemIconSize="25dp"
        app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"
        app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BtmNavUnselectedTextStyle"
        app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BtmNavSelectedTextStyle"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:itemRippleColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@android:color/transparent"
        app:activeIndicatorLabelPadding="5dp"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_nav" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


btm_nav
how can I solve this problem?
If I set the height to "wrap_content", I can see icons fully.
But then the height gets too high and I only want to set it to 70dp.

it seems like the previous comment has lost and the post is approved.
when you say "If I set the height to "wrap_content", I can see icons fully. But then the height gets too high and I only want to set it to 70dp."
please check the icons that you are using for the bottomNavigation. the height of them or and if only one of them has a higher height example 150dp, this will be the case to cover the main screen since you have set :
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp" ... />

open the menu_bottom_nav and check the icons how have you saved them and fix uniformly the height of them each. let me know if this resolves the issue since it seems like you are using custom ones and not the default from android. maybe when you have imported they are as svg or drawable. check the layout_heigh on each of them

I saved icons as svg files like this.

and then all of icons have 25dp height.

Could it be a problem that I'm using Empty View Activity instead of Bottom Navigation ViewActivity?

remove those lines from the code : android:viewportWidth="25" android:viewportHeight="25"
